# Issues with using nested loops to find strong numbers between two user input numbers

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops, factorial

So I am new to C, and have been doing some practice, and nested loops tend to be tougher for me.
This new problem about finding a strong number between two user input numbers is confusing me.
Essentially, a strong number is a number whose individual digit's factorials add up to the number. e.g. 145 = 1! + 4! + 5! = 1 + 24 + 120.

My issue is that after I input the two numbers, absolutely nothing happens. I am trying to print all strong numbers in between a range.

I have been trying to break the code down by pieces, and added comments to actually make it easier to understand for myself and others.

I am using the following function to find the strong numbers, the int main() just has the user input statements:

```
void strongno(int num1, int num2)
{
    // num1 and num2 are from user input in the in main() function
    int tot = 0; // to store the total number from each digits factorials
    for(int i = num1; i < num2; i++)
    //getting each individual number in the range, say i = 145
    {
        while(i)
        {
            int rem, fact = 1;

            rem = i % 10;// I am using this to get each digit alone, so first we get 5
            for(int j = 1; j <= rem; j++)
            {
                fact = fact * j;
                //the fact will give us the factorial of 5 = 120
            }
            tot = tot + fact; //tot will add all of the factorials of each remainder
            // while the number is not 0, so for now it is 120
            i = i / 10; // this will give us 14, and the cycle will repeat
        }
        // Once we have our total, we will compare the actual number i
        // to our calculated total. If it matches, it is a strong number
        if(tot == i)
        {
            printf("Strong Number: %d\n", i);
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }

}
```

I feel that the main issue may be with where I am actually placing the if statement or something, however I have tried arranging it and to no avail. The loops make sense to me, how they interact and all. I am trying not to look at the solution for this question, as that never helps, and would prefer guidance with the code I have, to work on a proper solution. Anything is appreciated.

Comment: `for(int i = num1; i < num2; i++)` but inside the loop you modify `i` to be `0` at `while (i) { .... i = i / 10;}` so the `for` loop never ends.

Comment: I would create a separate function that takes a single argument and returns whether that number is a strong number. Then you can call that inside your loop.

Comment: Oh I see now, I didn't realize that at all. Thank you for explaining that

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I just did what you suggested, and it solved the problem. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters it is better to declare the function with parameters of the unsigned type `unsigned int` instead of the signed type `int`

```
void strongno( unsigned int num1, unsigned int num2);
```

Otherwise you will have problems with negative numbers.

Using this while loop

```
while(i)
```

does not make a sense because it changes the variable `i` used in the preceding for loop. You need to use some intermediate variable that will assigned with the value of i.

For example

```
for( ; num1 < num2; num1++)
//getting each individual number in the range, say i = 145
{
    unsigned int i = num1;
    //...
```

Also the variable `tot` should be declared and initialized where it is used that is within the outer for loop.

```
for( ; num1 < num2; num1++)
//getting each individual number in the range, say i = 145
{
    unsigned int i = num1;
    unsigned int tot = 0; // to store the total number from each digits factorials
    //...
```

And this else statement

```
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
```

is just redundant. Remove it.